# Issues loading JPEG2000 RGBA format images

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, jpeg2000

I used OpenCV and Pillow to load the images.
Some jpeg2k images are loading & some are not.
My analysis is, images in RGB mode are getting loaded and jpeg2k images in RGBA mode are not getting loaded.
I checked with Kakadu viewer, and can view both RGB & RGBA mode images. Also with error below from OpenCV, I concluded images are not corrupt.

Pillow image description which are not loading:

```
<PIL.Jpeg2KImagePlugin.Jpeg2KImageFile image mode=RGBA size=6972x5225 at 0x124F1E7B8>
```

OpenCV warnings and error message for the same image:

```
[ WARN:0] global /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp (304) warningLogCallback OpenJPEG2000: Unknown marker

[ERROR:0] global /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp (299) errorLogCallback OpenJPEG2000: Error reading SPCod SPCoc element, Invalid code-block style found

[ERROR:0] global /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp (299) errorLogCallback OpenJPEG2000: Error reading COD marker

[ERROR:0] global /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp (299) errorLogCallback OpenJPEG2000: Marker handler function failed to read the marker segment
```

I am not an expert in image analysis, so need help to understand what libraries can be used to load the images.
I cannot upload image, since it is confidential. If I find similar images,  I will upload them.

- opencv-python==4.3.0.36
- Pillow==7.2.0

Comment: Which OpenCV version are you using ?

Comment: opencv-python==4.3.0.36

Comment: I found this [thread on Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14598), which could be helpful to you.

Comment: You don't specify your OS or its version. **ImageMagick** can read JPEG2000 files and convert them to anything else. Maybe install the latest/greatest JPEG2000 library and then install **ImageMagick** and convert your *"unhappy"* JPEG2000 images to something **OpenCV** is happier with - maybe a TIFF? Command would be `magick INPUT.JP2 OUTPUT.TIFF` It can also analyse a JPEG2000 and tell you its properties and that may help you find what is troubling **OpenCV**, use `magick identify -verbose IMAGE.JP2`

Answer (score 0):

I checked with below libs:
Rasterio, openjpeg , glymur, opencv, Matplotlib, pillow, ImageMagick

- Got appropriate response with gylumr as below:
  UserWarning: The file type brand was 'jph '.  It should be either 'jp2 ' or 'jpx '.
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning) The file type compatibility list ['jph '] is not valid.  All items should be members of ['jp2 ', 'jpx ', 'jpxb'].
- Opencv (cv2.imread) throws no error/logs and response is none , even after setting env variable OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL=INFO.
- Matplotlib loaded image as 4 channel empty array.
- Pillow loaded image as 4 channel empty array.

Came to know as we are using Kakadu to encode the image, which internally saves the image in jph format and then these images are converted to jp2 format images.

As I cannot find any existing library to load jph images, planning to write python wrapper to get NumPy array on top of Kakadu libs.

we are using kakadu only for mosaic images & that's why some images with 'jp2' were loading correctly & only mosaic images were not loading.